# Does every RMI request create a new thread on the server side?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, rmi

Is a new thread created on the server side for every single RMI call?
Where can I find information about this? I have googled it but the results are not good so far.

Answer (score 0):

> Is a new thread created in the server side for every single RMI call?

It isn't specified. In the Sun/Oracle implementation there is some thread conservation, due to client-side connection pooling. I read a long time ago that the IBM implementation uses a thread pool, but I've never verified it.

> Where can I find information about this?

It isn't specified.

> I have googled it but the results are not good so far.

It isn't specified. So you shouldn't rely on any specific behaviour. All the RMI Specification says about it that it isn't specified. All that means is that you can't assume it's single-threaded.

Comment: So everything depends on the implementation / vendor?

Comment: That's what 'it isn't specified' means.